# Display Drawer menu icons to the right of menu items

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I have a Navigation Drawer that opens from right to left, everything is working fine and the hamburger icon is working fine and it's in the right corner but menu icons are at the left of menu items.

How to move them to the right of menu items?

Please see the screen shot

[image]

This is my menu.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="none">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_navigation_home"
            android:title="@string/nav_menu_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_profile"
            android:title="@string/nav_profile" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_help"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_navigation_help"
            android:title="@string/nav_help" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="@string/nav_manage" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
            android:title="@string/nav_logout" />
    </group>
    <item android:title="@string/nav_communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_facebook"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_facebookx"
                android:title="@string/nav_face_page" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="@string/nav_contact" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

and this is my layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I searched a lot but didn't find anything related to this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need to Add Fragment and try make with reclyerview

Comment: @WaqarYounis Thank you for the hint :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `NavigationView` for handling `DrawerLayout`, make your `NavigationView` right to left by following code:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) //call this before super.onCreate
private void forceRtlIfSupported() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
    }
}
```

and set RTL flag in `AndroidManifiest.xml`

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

unfortunately above code only supported for **API 16** and later. In order to handle lower API, you can also implement `DrawerLayout` with `ListView` and do whatever you want. You can find a tutorial about this approach [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll give it a try and get back to you :)